# Avahi Reflector Ubuntu 18.10 Modprobe dot1q configuration on Hyper-V 2012 R2 Server

Tags: configuration, hyper-v, avahi

I am having a hard time configuring vlan interfaces on ubuntu desktop 18.10
Does anyone have any good templates or guides?  I found this guide and have followed it online:  http://chrisreinking.com/need-bonjour-across-vlans-set-up-an-avahi-gateway/

I have successfully created a Hyper-V VM with this image.  I put two nic on a virtual switch, and using Cisco 2960x series switches, I put each nic into a vlanned access port.  on on vlan 15 and one on vlan 40, both of which are 192.168.15.0/24 and 10.10.40.0/24.

They both successfully pull from dhcp on eth0 and eh1 from two different scopes, and when I turn on Avahi-reflector in step three of this guide, it works fine.  I can connect my iphone to vlan 40 ssid, and I can successfully see all printers on vlan 15.

I want to be able to do this with one Nic, using the further steps in that guide.  doing it my way, I didn't need to finish past step 3, but I want to be able to save server Nics if you know what I mean.

How do I successfully configure a dot1q subinterface on eth0?  Every time I try so sudo vconfig add eth0 15;40  it seems to work and sub interfaces are shown in ifconfig -a.  but when I run sudo dhclient eth0.15  it does not work, and takes a long time 5minutes to run, with no result.  Also it shows up in the Ubuntu GUI as a bluetooth vlan...?  I got the same results running ubuntu server 18.

In advance of this, I have since configured the switchport on cisco that eth0 is plugged into into a trunk port.  and eth0 successfully pulls a dhcp address from the native vlan.  eth0.15 never works for some reason...

any advice would be awesome!

Comment: essentially I am here, with no successfull pings leaving interface eth0.15 or eth0.40:  I followed Ubuntu's Wiki on VLANS to the T.

Comment: I think I just figured this out on my own.  If anyone is reading this let me know, I am very close to getting this working.  One thing I was missing, which there is very little instruction out there on how to do all the back-end stuff.  Is the Powershell command needed to configure a virtual Machine guest Nic as a Trunk Nic.  The command is Set-VMNetworkAdapterVlan -VMName ubuntuavahi -Trunk -AllowedVlanIdlist 1-40 - NativeVlanID 1